# How to tell scons to use MinGW instead of MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, mingw, zxing, scons

I'm trying to build the C++ port of zxing on Windows, but scons fails with:

```
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'
```

I have both VS2010 and MinGW installed, and scons tries to use the MSVC compiler, even though the SConscript file assumes gcc and use gcc-specific parameters, which causes the error.

How can I tell scons to use MinGW instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Scons uses MSVC compiler by default on windows. To set mignw compiler use tools parameter while creating Environment object.

```
env = Environment(tools = ['mingw'])
```

And then use  env.Program() instead of Program().

Comment: did not work for me. It says cc = gcc but then when building targets it still uses cl (bug?)

Comment: found it: it shall be env.Program(...) instead of Program(your_code) see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242206/scons-cant-pick-the-compiler-mingw

Comment: @ljgww Either call `env.Program` like you found out or change the default construction environment instead of creating a new one. You can do it by calling `DefaultEnvironment` instead of `Environment`.

Comment: As far as I know there may be some complication if yo won't also specify MinGW linker in the `tools`. I think it is called `gnulink`. There is also answer for a different question which shows another way to set tools: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391819/3052438

Answer (score 2):

Below is my working SConstruct for mingw on Windows:

```
import os

env = Environment(ENV={'PATH': os.environ['PATH'], 'TEMP': os.environ['TEMP']}, tools=['mingw'])
env.Program('main.cpp')
```

Windows Environment variables PATH and TEMP can be [set externally](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). Environment variable PATH should include the bin folder path of mingw.