# mingw -- cl is not recognized as an internal or external command -- my mingw in new and environment is true

Tags: python, visual-c++, mingw, scons, windows-console

recently I have downloaded latest version of mingw for win7 64bit.
also i have a program to build with scons but when i try to run it I see
 "cl is not recognized as an internal or external command" 
I search on internet and this site they suggest two solutions 
fist checking environment varible
second install this mingw from here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/

but I am sure my environment is true c:\mingw\bin
and I have a new version of mingw for win 7 64 bits

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Its looking for the windows compiler (cl) and cant find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell scons to use MinGW instead of MSVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161690/how-to-tell-scons-to-use-mingw-instead-of-msvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment to your question, its looking for the Windows compiler, which you probably dont have installed. According to the [SCons man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html), you can fix this as follows:

> MinGW
>
> The MinGW bin directory must be in your PATH environment variable or
>   the PATH variable under the ENV construction variable for SCons to
>   detect and use the MinGW tools. When running under the native Windows
>   Python interpreter, SCons will prefer the MinGW tools over the Cygwin
>   tools, if they are both installed, regardless of the order of the bin
>   directories in the PATH variable. If you have both MSVC and MinGW
>   installed and you want to use MinGW instead of MSVC, then you must
>   explictly tell SCons to use MinGW by passing
>
> tools=['mingw']
>
> to the Environment() function, because SCons will prefer the MSVC
>   tools over the MinGW tools.

So, change the instantiation of your Environment to something like this:

```
env = Environment(tools=['mingw'])
```

If you need to specify more in the Environment constructor, you can do something like this:

```
env = Environment(tools=['mingw'], variables = command_line_vars)
```

Comment: I have installed Microsoft visual studio 2010 I mean I have MSVC tools but I do not enter it's path in my environment variable and I just need mingw. So as you sad I have to strictly tell scons to use mingw but the problem is I tried to change but in my code there is  "env = Environment(variables = command_line_vars)" and  if I change  command_line_vars to tools=['mingw'] my code does not work.Can u suggest me a way to keep on both of them? I am not familiar with scons and python. By the way I thank very much for being patient