# SCons can't pick the compiler (MinGW)

Tags: c++, scons

I have a simple SConstruct file with the following code

```
path = ['C:\\MinGW\\bin']
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path})

Program(target = 'myprogram', source = ['main.cpp'])
```

running 'scons' on cmd gives the following error message:

```
cl /Fomain.obj /c main.cpp /TP /nologo
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [main.obj] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

It looks like SCons does not pick my compiler (MinGW). What am I doing wrong?
I'm on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting *tools* variable in *environment* you should use *env.Program('...')* instead of *Program('...'*). Below is my working SConstruct for mingw:

```
path = ['C:\\Dev\\MinGW\\x64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1\\mingw64\\bin']
temp = 'C:\\Temp'

env = Environment(ENV={'PATH': path, 'TEMP': temp}, 
                  tools=['mingw'])

env.Program('solver-tikhonov.cpp')
```

Answer (score 3):

SCons is trying to build with the default Windows tools, namely `cl`, which is the visual studio compiler. You need to tell it to use the mingw toolset, as follows:

```
path = ['C:\\MinGW\\bin']
env = Environment(tools=['mingw'], ENV = {'PATH' : path})
```

After doing this, if it still cant find the mingw compiler, you can set it as follows:

```
env.Replace(CC='path/to/mingw/cc/compiler',
            CXX='path/to/mingw/c++/compiler')
```

Comment: Both ways do not work.

Comment: @Amani what's the resulting output? Is it still looking for cl? or is it looking for the right compiler now?